# How to detect the noise type and remove it from image matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, noise

I have an image matrix I want a way to detect the noise type, and then find a filter to remove that noise, using MATLAB.

My problem: I draw a histogram of the image, which looked the same as a histogram for salt and paper noise (my image has only three pixels of noise). I tried the median filter to remove noise, but it changed the image more than just removing noise.

```
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
1  100 100 100 100 100  1   1   1
1  100 100 100 100 100 100  1   1
1  100 100  1   1  100 100  1  100
1  100 100  1   1  100 100  1   1
1  100 100 100 100 100 100  1   1
1  100 100 100 100 100 100  1   1
1  100 100  1   1   1   1   1   1
1  100 100  1   80  1   1   1   90
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've removed your request for help detecting edges, as that is unrelated to the main question. Please keep each question to one single topic. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A median filter will cut off the corners of your image like that. Given that your image is more or less binary, a simple way of removing the noise *in this case* is to remove isolated pixels: pixels surrounded by values much lower than itself.

This can be easily accomplished in MATLAB with the Image Processing Toolbox using the morphological opening (`imopen`):

```
img = [1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
       1  100 100 100 100 100  1   1   1
       1  100 100 100 100 100 100  1   1
       1  100 100  1   1  100 100  1  100
       1  100 100  1   1  100 100  1   1
       1  100 100 100 100 100 100  1   1
       1  100 100 100 100 100 100  1   1
       1  100 100  1   1   1   1   1   1
       1  100 100  1   80  1   1   1   90];
img = padarray(img,[1,1]); % proper boundary conditions needed
img = max(imopen(img,[1,1]),imopen(img,[1;1]));
img = img(2:end-1,2:end-1); % remove padding again
```

We're using two openings: one with a SE `[1,1]`, and one with an SE `[1;1]`. Either one of them might remove 1-pixel thick lines, but no lines will be removed by both. Thus, we take the maximum of the two results: if both filters remove the pixel, it will stay removed, but if only one removes it, we want to keep this pixel (it belongs to a line).

There are other ways of identifying isolated pixels, but this method is quite simple to implement based on an existing function in the toolbox.

Comment: how can i know for sure the kind and type of noise this image ? i do not think its salt and paper noise

Comment: @LounaAkkad: You know what noise an image has because you analyze how it was obtained. You analyze the *sources* of the noise (either theoretically or experimentally) and know their characteristics. I have no idea how your image was obtained (seems to have gone through a lot of processing) so cannot tell you anything about the noise.

Comment: actually i dont know i have this matrix and asked to guess the kind of noise and remove it ,so i guessed it is kind of impulse noise ,but i want to be sure

Comment: @LounaAkkad: yes, this looks like impulse noise, since only a few pixels are affected, and they are affected strongly.